# ifstream.open() sets failbit in eclipse cdt?

Tags: c++, eclipse-cdt, ifstream

I am learning C++ file I/O and am having difficulty with opening a file for reading. I have tried a simple isolated file input program in both Eclipse CDT (Ubuntu 18.04) and Visual Studios (Windows 10). In Visual Studios, it reads the file without any problem but in Eclipse it set the failbit flag when I open the file. I've attempted to .clear() the failbit flag to see if it would still be able to read the file but it is reading it as if it is empty.

My program is as follows:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    ifstream f;
    f.open("test.txt");
    if (!f.is_open()) {
        cout << "file could not be opened" << endl;
        cout << "failbit? " << (f.fail() ? "yes" : "no") << endl;
        return -1;
    }
    cout << "file opened successfully" << endl;
    string line;
    int i = 0;
    while (f.peek() != EOF) {
        getline(f, line);
        cout << "line " << i << ": " << line << endl;
        i++;
    }
}
```

This is working on VS but i need it to work on eclipse too. Open to any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: Undoubtedly the reason is that the file is being looked for in a different place than you expect. So the fail bit is being set because, under Eclipse, your program does not find the file. Try using an absolute path for your file, instead of a relative one.

Comment: If it's working from one IDE but not from the other, my guess would be that those two don't set the same working directory. Since you pass a relative path to the file, it's going to be relative to that working directory, and if it's not right, well, the file won't be found.

Answer (score 1):

Most versions of Eclipse execute the program from a different folder from where the project is located, if you have the file in the project directory, try moving/copying it to the debug directory where the executable is located.